# How to actually concatenate two Strings?

Tags: programming, c++, string

I'm using the SPISlave library, and I have the following code snippet:

```cpp
String arg;

SPISlave.onData([arg](uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
  data[len] = 0;
  arg += String((char *)data);
  // ...
}
```

The compiler doesn't like my string concatenation, though:

> /home/lars/sketch_apr01a/sketch_apr01a.ino: In lambda function:
>   sketch_apr01a:65:12: error: passing 'const String' as 'this' argument
>   of 'String& String::operator+=(const String&)' discards qualifiers
>   [-fpermissive]
>          arg += String((char *)data);

I've tried other versions as well, with similar results:

- `arg.concat((char *)data)`
- `arg = arg + String((char *)data)`
- `arg += String((const char *)data)`

So how exactly do I write this unusual operation?

Comment: Funny, on avr-g++ it's fine (with warnings about store duration). Anyway, you are capturing the arg variable by value, so it won't affect variable outside lambda function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda is capturing `arg` by copy, which is most certainly not what
you want. And since it doesn't have the `mutable` qualifier, the
captured parameters are not modifiable. Hence the compiler error.

You could get rid of the error by qualifying the capture as `mutable`,
but you would then be modifying the captured copy of `arg`, not the
original one. The correct solution would be to capture the String by
reference instead of capturing by copy. See [Lambda
expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

But then, I concur with Michel Keijzers that avoiding Strings altogether
is a better option.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the insight and correct answer too (upvoted)

Answer (score 2):

Actually for such string concatenation (which is in a function that may be called a lot), this could result in memory fragmentation, an on most Arduinos the memory will be soon too scattered that no useful memory is left.

Instead, it's better to create beforehand a buffer with the maximum size of the string you want to handle, like:

```
static const int MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH = 256;

char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];
```

And use the function `strcat` or `strncat` for concatenating two strings; there are generic C functions.

Comment: Fair enough, and good advice in general.  But I'd still like to know the answer to my question. :-)

Comment: I wonder what error you get when using concat (cannot be a String passing operation error). Maybe some casting to const.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const int MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH = 32;
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH];

sprintf(buffer, "%s%s", string1, string2);
```